# Is it possible to remove elements from template based on props VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

I am wondering if it possible to dynamically remove html components from a template. I have the following template. Popup is a custom vue component that takes its contents and displays it in a popup window.

When I give the boolean prop "usePopup" I would like to somehow display the div normally in the place that it is called (not in a popup). Is there some way I can achieve this? Could I remove the html elements dynamically somehow? Would it be possible to remove the Popup elements from the template manually and add them dynamically/conditionally?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Popup>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        </Popup>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    name: "dynamic-element-removal",
    created(){
        // If usePopup is false remove Popup so that only CustomComponent renders
    },
    props : {
        usePopup: {
            default : true,
            type : Boolean
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`portal-vue`](https://portal-vue.linusb.org/) for Vue 2 to move content to a specified target:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <portal :to="usePopup ? 'popup' : 'container'">
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
    </portal>

    <Popup v-if="usePopup">
      <portal-target name="popup" />
    </Popup>
    <div v-else>
      <portal-target name="container" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/teleporting-elements-in-vue-2-92jxt?file=/src/components/MyComponent.vue)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: This is included natively in Vue 3 https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/teleport.html

Comment: Just be aware that `teleport` and `portal-vue` are not 1-to-1 implementations. They have different requirements that prevent the above example from working in Vue 3.

Answer (score 1):

first you srsly should read the docs [Conditional Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

second, this is what you want:

```html
<template>
    <div v-if="usePopup">
        <Popup> <--- the magic happens here
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
        </Popup>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
     your normal div content
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    name: "dynamic-element-removal",
    created(){
        // If usePopup is false remove Popup so that only CustomComponent renders
    },
    props : {
        usePopup: {
            default : true,
            type : Boolean
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Super helpful answer. I am asking is it possible, if not, why not and is there a clean way around it.

Comment: Not too sure why my comments were deleted.